# How can I rotate 2 or more html banners (Adnetwork tags) on a single banner space

Tags: html, banner, candisplaybannerads

I got this code for rotatating multiple images on a space

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
/*
 Copyright 2017 The PCman Website Rotating Banner Code
 https://www.thepcmanwebsite.com
 This code is free to use provided this notice is not removed.
 Create your own custom banner code with banners
*/
mybanners=
[
"<a href=\"http://example123.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"http://example123.com/banner.gif\" width=\"468\" height=\"60\" alt=\"Click here for example\" title=\"Click here for example\" border=\"0\"></a>",
"<a href=\"http://example.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"http://example.com/banner.gif\" width=\"468\" height=\"60\" alt=\"Click here for example\" title=\"Click here for example\" border=\"0\"></a>"
]
randomNumber = Math.random()
var show_mybanners = mybanners[Math.floor(randomNumber * mybanners.length)]
document.write(show_mybanners);
// --></script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://example.com" target=\"_blank\"><img src="http://example.com/banner.gif" width="468" height="60" alt="Click here for example" title="Click here for example" border="0"></a>
</noscript>
```

It rotate a new image everytime page rotate.
I want a similer code like this for rotating iframe (Multiple Adnetwork) banners

Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: You haven't actually included any code, please review the question

Comment: I added it now please help me in this regard